# Quais as diferenças entre InputStreamReader e Scanner em Java

Tags: java, scanner

Tive conhecimento da leitura de dados pelo `Scanner`, sei superficialmente seu funcionamento, entretanto me deparei com alguns exemplos utilizando uma classe chamada `InputStreamReader` para leitura de dados.

Quais são as diferenças entre essas abordagens e no caso de serem utilizadas para a mesma finalidade, qual a melhor e o porque.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A classe [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) faz a leitura de dados **binários**, não importa a fonte (ex.: `FileInputStream` para ler arquivos, `ByteArrayInputStream` para ler de um array de bytes, `socket.getInputStram()` para ler de um soquete, `System.in` para ler do console, etc). Já a classe [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) faz a leitura de dados **textuais**, ou seja, strings compostas de caracteres Unicode (*code units* de 16 bits, incluindo *surrogate pairs*).

A função do [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) é servir como um adaptador ([*Adapter*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter)) entre as duas classes - lê bytes de um lado, converte em caracteres do outro, através do uso de uma [codificação de caracteres](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_caracteres) (*encoding*). Ou seja, ele é um `Reader` que recebe um `InputStream` na construção, consumindo dados desse *stream* e apresentando-os como caracteres para o consumidor.

Enquanto um `Reader` é uma classe "de mais baixo nível" (sua função é ler caracteres, não mais, não menos) o [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) é uma classe mais especializada, destinada a **interpretar** um texto subjacente de diversas formas (ex.: uma sequência de dígitos pode ser um número, `true` pode ser um boolean), inclusive usando expressões regulares. Sua função não é tratar *streams*, inclusive ela **delega** essa responsabilidade para uma classe especializada - como o `InputStream` ou o `Reader`.

No fim das contas, você usa a(s) classe(s) mais apropriada(s) para o seu propósito. Inclusive podendo usar as 3 ao mesmo tempo:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("arquivo.txt"); // Lê bytes do arquivo
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"); // Transforma em caracteres
Scanner s = new Scanner(r); // Prepara-se para interpretar esses caracteres de modo semântico
```

Answer (score 3):

Além do tamanho do *buffer* padrão do primeiro ser bem maior que do segundo, o [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) foi desenhado para ler [*streams*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227339/101) de uma forma geral e com bastante controle sobre como fazer a leitura embora não se preocupe com o conteúdo, enquanto que o [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) tem função mais específica mas possui melhores ferramentas para controlar o conteúdo lido.

Normalmente o `Scanner` é usado para leitura em console, embora possa ser usado para ler arquivos, ele pode ser útil em arquivos pouco estruturados como no caso do XML. Esta preferência se dá porque ele lê *tokens* de dados, ele compreende o que está sendo lido - fazendo um *parsing* - e isto facilita a entrada de dados onde não há garantias do que pode ser recebido. Por ser uma classe para ser usada de forma mais específica e simplificada ela não é *thread-safe*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Em essência, a aplicatividade do Scanner seria par leitura de dados em console, enquanto o InputStreamReader seria para leitura e manipulação de arquivos externos? Mas nada me impediria de ler um dado do console com o InputStreamReader certo?

Comment: Não necessariamente, ele pode ser usado para outras fontes de dados, inclusive ele pode receber *streams* diversos, só citei o console porque ele é muito usado para isto já que dados no console precisam ser interpretados antes de serem considerados dados manipuláveis pela aplicação. Ambos podem ser usados para a mesma coisa mas operam de formas diferentes por isto um é mais usado que o outro em determinadas situações. Se você usar o `InputStreamReader` para ler o que vem do console e não vier o que você espera, tem pouco a fazer.