# O que é stream?

Tags: arquivo, terminologia, memória, java-8, stream

Tanto em PHP como em C#, linguagens que ultimamente tenho utilizado no meu dia a dia, tenho me deparado com um termo em comum: Stream.

Sempre quando eu ouço a palavra *Stream*, a primeira coisa que me vem à cabeça é Youtube, entre outros sites, que são geralmente chamados de "sites que transmitem vídeo via streaming".

Porém nas linguagens citadas a cima, o termo geralmente está relacionado à leitura e escrita de dados na memória ou em um arquivo.

Por exemplo, no PHP temos uma função chamada `stream_get_contents` que é responsável por obter em uma *string* os conteúdos de um `resource` aberto pela função `fopen`.

Já no C# acabei esbarrando nesse termo quando precisei usar a classe `FileStream` e `MemoryStream`, que me lembrou um pouco os *wrappers* que o PHP utiliza para ler o buffer de saída, arquivos ou mesmo a memória propriamente dita (através dos *wrapper* `php://output`, `php://memory` e afins).

Resumindo a minha dúvida:

- Qual é o significado de Stream afinal de contas?
- Eu queria saber se esse *stream* do PHP e do Csharp tem alguma relação com o "streaming de vídeos" de sites como o Youtube.
- Todas as linguagens que trabalham com manipulação de dados, como arquivos, arquivos temporários, memória ou *buffer* de saída, também usam esse *Stream*?

Comment: Ouço muito falar de _stream_ quando falam de Java 8... Também quero saber! Boa pergunta

Comment: Relacionada: [Como realmente entender Streams?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49831/28595)

Comment: A galerinha que anda negativando as perguntas poderia explicar o motivo do negativo. Assim, poderíamos aumentar o nível intelectual das perguntas do site, sabendo onde está o defeito e corrigindo o que precisa ser melhorado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quase tudo já foi respondido em [Como realmente entender Streams?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49831/101).

Nada a ver com *streaming de video* diretamente, embora a técnica seja a mesma. Você acessa um recurso que vai te dando a informação que deseja conforme vai solicitando, a forma exata como isso ocorre não importa.

Em geral linguagens não possuem *streams*, bibliotecas sim, então qualquer uma pode ter. As mais modernas possuem na biblioteca padrão. Você pode criar seus *streams*.

Java 8 inventou um tal de Stream que não deixa de ser um mecanismo como este que estamos falando, mas é usado em outro contexto, é quase o mesmo que o LINQ do C#, é uma forma de manipular enumeráveis sob demanda.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Vou tentar responder de forma genérica, sem ligação direta a uma linguagem específica. Eu não entendo Stream como um recurso específico de uma linguagem, e sim uma técnica/algorítimo.

> Qual é o significado de Stream afinal de contas?

Como a própria tradução livre explica, Stream é uma corrente, é um fluxo de dados, nas linguagens de programação em geral trata-se de transferir um conteúdo/bytes de tamanho conhecido ou não de um "local" ao outro, local nesse caso sempre está relacionado ao hardware (ram, hdd, flash, usb, ethernet, etc) ainda que seja virtualizado, internamente essa comunicação geralmente é realizada via SO.

> Eu queria saber se esse stream do PHP e do Csharp tem alguma relação com o "streaming de vídeos" de sites como o Youtube.

Como esclarecido com a resposta pra sua pergunta anterior, sim, pois trata-se de transferir conteúdos/bytes de um ponto ao outro.

> Todas as linguagens que trabalham com manipulação de dados, como arquivos, arquivos temporários, memória ou buffer de saída, também usam esse Stream?

Neste caso precisamos esclarecer que existem Streams que você já conhece o tamanho, um arquivo em disco por exemplo, e existem streams como os de som e imagem que vão chegando ao passo que são disponibilizados por um servidor. Então na minha opinião sim, ainda que nem todas as linguagens sejam pra web, ou permitam transferência de conteúdos de tamanhos dinâmicos, ou que nem mesmo tenham uma classe chamada Stream, stream nesse caso é somente um nome dados a essa técnica.