# Existe alguma diferença de performance entre escrever um arquivo como resposta e escrever em um arquivo por partes (buffer)?

Tags: servidor, download, sistema-de-arquivos, stream-de-arquivos

Eu tenho uma instância t2.micro na amazon onde eu utilizo IIS 10 como servidor e webforms na aplicação (C#).

Em uma determinada parte da aplicação, eu preciso pegar uma lista de arquivos de imagens de uma determinada pasta, zipar ela e responder como download para o usuário.

O problema é que em um determinado caso específico, quando o arquivo ZIP chegou a 1GB, o servidor simplesmente trava quando o usuário clica no botão para fazer o download desse arquivo ZIP.

Eu gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas, não referente ao problema acima, mas uma dúvida técnica a respeito de como funcionam as respostas de download, quando você escreve ela através de um [Stream](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227339/o-que-%C3%A9-stream) ou algo do tipo.

Para o servidor, existe alguma diferença entre escrever uma resposta de um arquivo diretamente e escrever utilizando buffer (utilizando um `while`, por exemplo)?

Exemplo 1 - Diretamente:

```
// headers para download
readfile($filename);
```

Exemplo 2 - Por Buffer:

```
// headers para download

$handler = fopen($filename);

while(feof($handler) !== false) {
   echo fgets($handler, 4096);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado downvoter, gostaria de um feedback

Answer (score 11):

Há diferenças sim.

No primeiro caso o arquivo será carregado inteiramente na memória do servidor antes de ser enviado para o cliente.

No segundo caso o arquivo será parcialmente carregado na memória e sendo enviado aos poucos para o cliente. Desta forma você compromete menos a memória do servidor, pois ele poderá atender múltiplas requisições consumindo pouca memória para cada uma delas.

Sobre o seu problema, provavelmente você está utilizando-se do primeiro caso (carregando o arquivo inteiro na memória), fazendo com que o servidor t2.micro (que curiosamente tem [1 GB de memória RAM](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/ec2/instance-types/)) trave e pare de responder.

Em termos de performance, usando a técnica do segundo caso, o download não só economizará memória como também começará mais cedo a ser disponibilizado para o usuário, pois o tempo de carregar parte de um arquivo *vs* um arquivo inteiro na memória do servidor são bem diferentes.

Há uma [implementação parcial](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/06/writing-download-server-part-i-always.html) feita em Java com Spring na qual é possível também reproduzir este comportamento, mostrando também as duas situações.