# Qual a real diferença do fs.readFile() e do fs.createReadSream()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, stream-de-arquivos, fs

A questão é que eu consigo usar as duas funções para fazer a mesma coisa. Por exemplo:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../arquivo.txt')

fs.readFile(filePath, 
  (error, fileContent) => console.log(fileContent.toString()))

fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  .on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()))
```

Eu sei que o `createReadStream()` retorna uma stream, mas não sei exatamente todas as coisas que uma stream pode fazer. A questão é que eu estou usando o módulo `fs` que acredito eu que seja focado na interação com outros arquivos, se eu já tenho duas funções para ler um arquivo, uma assíncrona e outra síncrona (`.readFile()` e `.readFileSync()`) e me retornar o conteúdo dele, por que eu preciso de outra que me retorne uma stream? Qual será a vantagem nisso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `fs.readFile` lê o arquivo especificado e carrega todo o seu conteúdo para uma variável. Isso significa que o programa precisará alocar memória o suficiente para comportar o que está contido no arquivo.

Embora, para arquivos pequenos, o efeito seja o "mesmo" (de modo que `createReadStream` pode até trazer um certo *overhead*), utilizar `readFile` torna-se **impraticável** quando o tamanho do arquivo é significativamente expressivo, já que não há memória o suficiente para a operação.

Quando se cria uma *stream* (tal como o `createReadStream`) faz, não é mais necessário ler todo o arquivo de uma vez. Portanto, alocações menores (porém mais prolongadas) são necessárias, de modo que se processa um pedaço do arquivo por vez.

Em suma:

- Funções como o `readFile` tendem a ser mais apropriadas para operações em arquivos que comportam pouco conteúdo.
- Funções como a `createReadStream` são ideias para lidar com grandes arquivos, de modo que permitem o processamento do arquivo em "lotes".

Sobre o conceito mais genérico de *Stream*, sugiro ler [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227339/69296) ou o [artigo na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

---

Sobre o `readFileSync` ou `readFile`, o comportamento é o mesmo: carregam todo o conteúdo do arquivo na memória do programa. Streams são um paradigma um pouco diferente dos conceitos "clássicos" de sincronismo e assincronismo. Estão, não obstante, mais próximas do *assincronismo*, já que não bloqueiam o *event loop* (ao contrário de métodos `*Sync`).

Comment: Entendi mas eu não tenho quase noção nenhuma do que seria um arquivo grande e um pequeno, vou dar uma pesquisada em relação a isso, obrigado pela ajuda você tem me ajudado bastante nas minhas duas primeiras perguntas e foi mal pelo péssimo uso da gramática kkkk, mas enfim só queria agradecer pela ajuda msm.

Comment: @arturHamann, imagine um .csv com milhões de linhas e você quer analisar uma a uma. Carregá-lo todo de uma vez é impraticável em detrimento de seu tamanho. Nesse tipo de situação, é ideal utilizar _streams_. E que gramática, sô? Só formatei os nomes das funções! :-)